An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request when Scaffolding an Entity
To give you some context:
I am currently working on a simple CRUD Scaffolded MVC table.
And I am having trouble Implementing the Relationships.
Simple independent tables work just fine as is just scaffold the Model and that's it.
But as I tried to implement a relationship as so:
 public class Activo
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Marca { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Modelo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Tarjeta_Video { get; set; }
        public int? ID_Usuario { get; set; }
        public int? ID_Procesador { get; set; }
        public int? ID_Memoria { get; set; }
        public int? ID_DiscoDuro { get; set; }

        // Navigation properties
        [ForeignKey("ID_Usuario")]
        public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ID_Procesador")]
        public virtual Procesador Procesador { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ID_Memoria")]
        public virtual Memoria Memoria { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ID_DiscoDuro")]
        public virtual DiscoDuro DiscoDuro { get; set; }
    }

This is the updated Scaffolded Controlled:
// GET: Activos/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["ID_DiscoDuro"] = new SelectList(_context.DiscoDuro, "id", "Marca");
            ViewData["ID_Memoria"] = new SelectList(_context.Memoria, "id", "Marca");
            ViewData["ID_Procesador"] = new SelectList(_context.Procesador, "id", "Marca");
            ViewData["ID_Usuario"] = new SelectList(_context.Usuario, "id", "ApellidoMaterno");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Activos/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("id,Marca,Modelo,Tarjeta_Video,ID_Usuario,ID_Procesador,ID_Memoria,ID_DiscoDuro")] Activo activo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(activo);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["ID_DiscoDuro"] = new SelectList(_context.DiscoDuro, "id", "Modelo", activo.ID_DiscoDuro);
            ViewData["ID_Memoria"] = new SelectList(_context.Memoria, "id", "Modelo", activo.ID_Memoria);
            ViewData["ID_Procesador"] = new SelectList(_context.Procesador, "id", "Modelo", activo.ID_Procesador);
            ViewData["ID_Usuario"] = new SelectList(_context.Usuario, "id", "ApellidoMaterno", activo.ID_Usuario);
            return View(activo);
        }

And this is my View:
   <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Marca" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Marca" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Marca" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Modelo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Modelo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Modelo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Tarjeta_Video" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Tarjeta_Video" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Tarjeta_Video" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ID_Usuario" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ID_Usuario" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ID_Usuario"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ID_Procesador" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ID_Procesador" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ID_Procesador"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ID_Memoria" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ID_Memoria" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ID_Memoria"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ID_DiscoDuro" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ID_DiscoDuro" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ID_DiscoDuro"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

So the idea is fairly simple or at least I thought it was. I just wanted to have a fetch data on the controllers that will then send it to the Views via a ViewData which will be used via the ViewBag object. And it somewhat works.
As I try to create the Activo it lets me dropdown and see all the available data that is within the Memoria, DiscoDuro and so on tables.
But once I press Create this error appear:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetListItemsWithValueField()

I have tried redoing the way I send the data. But I just can't seem to fix it. I have also read on some post that this problem could be because of the HTTP Post has the same name as others. This is not the case as when I do not use the DropDown menu meaning I just hard input the Id they do work.
This made me believe the problem is in the way I am using these values.
I know its probably not correctly grabbing the input value but as I am fairly novice in Razor Pages and MVC I just can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing and yet alone how to fix it. I just feel lost.
Any guidance fixing, redoing this problem or just any way to make this easier, doable or just better I would really really appreciate it.
Thank you for your time.
This is the full CallStack:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetListItemsWithValueField()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetEnumerator()
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>..ctor(IEnumerable<T> collection)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.DefaultHtmlGenerator.GenerateGroupsAndOptions(string

optionLabel, IEnumerable selectList,
ICollection currentValues)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.DefaultHtmlGenerator.GenerateSelect(ViewContext
viewContext, ModelExplorer modelExplorer, string optionLabel, string
expression, IEnumerable selectList,
ICollection currentValues, bool allowMultiple, object
htmlAttributes)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.SelectTagHelper.Process(TagHelperContext
context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext
context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.RunAsync(TagHelperExecutionContext
executionContext)
AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Activos_Create.b__19_0()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.GetChildContentAsync(bool
useCachedResult, HtmlEncoder encoder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext
context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.g__Awaited|0_0(Task
task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, int i, int count)
AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Activos_Create.ExecuteAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage
page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage
page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData,
ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable
statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|22_0(ResourceInvoker
invoker, IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|30_0<TFilter,
TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next,
Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter,
TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref
bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker
invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext
context)


Post the actual full exception text, including the call stack. The parts you posted suggest the code is trying to render a list containing nulls or objects with null properties

It's clear the problem is caused when rendering the combos. Instead of just passing the DbSets to the SelectList constructor, load them properly with eg ToList or ToListAsync and inspect them. Even better, use queries that return only the ID and display property you want instead of the entire entity. If a label is expected to be null you can easily add ??"" or ??"(Unknown)" in the Select clause. You can easily cache those results so you don't have to load the same lookup data over and over.

You could try this below code which will help you resolve the NullReferenceException error and allows you to insert the data:
ActivoController.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ActivoProject;
using ActivoProject.Models;

namespace ActivoProject.Controllers
{
    public class ActivoController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ActivoController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Activo/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            PopulateDropdowns();
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Activo/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Marca,Modelo,Tarjeta_Video,ID_Usuario,ID_Procesador,ID_Memoria,ID_DiscoDuro")] Activo activo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(activo);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            PopulateDropdowns(activo);
            return View(activo);
        }

        private void PopulateDropdowns(Activo activo = null)
        {
            ViewData["ID_Usuario"] = new SelectList(_context.Usuario, "Id", "ApellidoMaterno", activo?.ID_Usuario);
            ViewData["ID_Procesador"] = new SelectList(_context.Procesador, "Id", "Modelo", activo?.ID_Procesador);
            ViewData["ID_Memoria"] = new SelectList(_context.Memoria, "Id", "Modelo", activo?.ID_Memoria);
            ViewData["ID_DiscoDuro"] = new SelectList(_context.DiscoDuro, "Id", "Modelo", activo?.ID_DiscoDuro);

        }
    }
    }

Activo.cs:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System;

namespace ActivoProject.Models
{
    public class Activo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string? Marca { get; set; } // Nullable

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string? Modelo { get; set; } // Nullable

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string? Tarjeta_Video { get; set; } // Nullable

        public int? ID_Usuario { get; set; }
        public int? ID_Procesador { get; set; }
        public int? ID_Memoria { get; set; }
        public int? ID_DiscoDuro { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ID_Usuario")]
        public virtual Usuario? Usuario { get; set; } // Nullable

        [ForeignKey("ID_Procesador")]
        public virtual Procesador? Procesador { get; set; } // Nullable

        [ForeignKey("ID_Memoria")]
        public virtual Memoria? Memoria { get; set; } // Nullable

        [ForeignKey("ID_DiscoDuro")]
        public virtual DiscoDuro? DiscoDuro { get; set; } // Nullable
    }

}

Create.cshtml:
@model ActivoProject.Models.Activo

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Activo</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Marca" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Marca" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Marca" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Modelo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Modelo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Modelo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Tarjeta_Video" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Tarjeta_Video" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Tarjeta_Video" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ID_Usuario" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ID_Usuario" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ID_Usuario"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ID_Usuario" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ID_Procesador" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ID_Procesador" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ID_Procesador"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ID_Procesador" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ID_Memoria" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ID_Memoria" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ID_Memoria"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ID_Memoria" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ID_DiscoDuro" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ID_DiscoDuro" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ID_DiscoDuro"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ID_DiscoDuro" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}

